# Workout location using Health Kit

Tags: ios, ios11, healthkit

I haven't been able to find a way to read GPS data from an `HKWorkout` using Apple's `HealthKit` SDK... there seems to be a way to *save* location data using `HKWorkoutRouteBuilder` / `HKWorkoutRoute`, but no way to *read* it.

I guess this kind of makes sense because you'd have to get the user's permission to access location data which Apple is super sensitive about. Perhaps there's a workaround somewhere, could anyone shine some light, please?

Comment: did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 4):

Apple has now provided a complete guide of getting this information: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/workouts_and_activity_rings/reading_route_data

The guide is actually recommending using `HKAnchoredObjectQuery` instead of `HKSampleQuery` because route data can change.

Answer (score 3):

Use `HKSampleQuery` to query for `HKWorkoutRoute` samples, using the predicate returned by `predicateForObjects(from:)` ([docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkquery/1614773-predicateforobjects)). Then use `HKWorkoutRouteQuery` ([docs](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwj0w4So7KvYAhUpllQKHXC9DvsQFggpMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.apple.com%2Fdocumentation%2Fhealthkit%2Fhkworkoutroutequery&usg=AOvVaw2NjYWqiVoB3XjqfFIvpvxY)) to query for the `CLLocations` belonging to a specific `HKWorkoutRoute`. Don't forget to request authorization to read both the types identified by `HKWorkoutTypeIdentifier` and `HKWorkoutRouteTypeIdentifier`.